# Javascript alert is opening a PHP include file and not staying on the home page

Tags: javascript, php, alert

The home page is index.php and it contains an include for a different sidebar_signin_block.php file that creates a user login block. In the sidebar_signin_block.php if the login succeeds I am using this javascript to send them to a login success splash page: `echo "<script>window.open('login-success.php','_self')</script>";}`Now on the other hand if the login fails I have an else statement with a javascript for an alert box that looks like this: `echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect please try again')</script>";`

Here is my problem that I need help with. While at the index.php page if the login succeeds or if it fails the included file sidebar_signin_block.php opens up and is the web page in view. I want to stay on the home page index.php and do not want the sidebar_signin_block.php page to open. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Just in case you need it for diagnosing I am including the entire sidebar-signin-block.php file below:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sidebar-signin-block.php">

        <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="white">


            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="ffffff" colspan="2" align="center"><h2>User Login</h2></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><h3 style="margin-top:7px;"><a href="nonadmin_user_forgot_password.php" target="_blank" title="Reset Your Lost Password">Forgot Password?</a></h3></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2" align="center"><div style="padding-top:5px;"><span style="font-size:20px;">Don't have an account?<br /><a href="/includes/register-user.php" title="Register with us!" target="_self">Sign Up</a> is <em>quick</em> and <em>easy</em>!</span></div></td>

        </table>
    </form>

    <?php 

// Connecting to the database and making the Bcrypt functions available
include("admin/includes/connect.php");
include ("lib/password.php");

// Gathering and sanitizing user login input
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $email = trim(((isset($conn) && is_object($conn)) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']) :((trigger_error  ("[MySQLConverterToo] Fix the mysql_escape_string() call! This code does not work.", E_USER_ERROR)) ? "" : "")));

        $pass = trim(((isset($conn) && is_object($conn)) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']) : ((trigger_error   ("[MySQLConverterToo] Fix the mysql_escape_string() call! This code does not work.", E_USER_ERROR)) ? "" : "")));

         // Checking the database records for the user login input
        $hash_query = "select nonadmin_user_pass from nonadmin_user_login where email='$email'";{
                $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $hash_query);}
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
                $fetch_pass = $row['nonadmin_user_pass'];
                    }
        // If the user email and password matches we start a session                               
        if ((password_verify($pass, $fetch_pass)) == 1){

              // Verifying user login success with splash page then sending user back to the home page
              $_SESSION['email']=$email;
              echo "<script>window.open('login-success.php','_self')</script>";}
    // When the user login fails an alert is given to inform them
    else {
    echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect please try again')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bro , its not java , its javascript

Comment: Hudixt thank you for pointing that out. I edited the post and removed the space between the two words.

Comment: I was talking about the tag and title, there you wrote java

Comment: Hudixt thanks again for your input and I fixed the title and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login form's target (`action` attribute) points back to the sidebar file.  Thus when the user presses the submit button, the browser requests that page and loads it into the current frame.

To avoid this, add a `submit` event handler to the form which sends the form data to the server using AJAX and then returns `false`.  This suppresses the normal browser behavior of loading the form's target.  The AJAX response should indicate whether the login succeeded or failed, at which point you can load the splash page or show the alert, as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer Phari I appreciate your help. I am not familiar with AJAX so I am going to study up on this and see if I can get your solution implemented.

Answer (score 0):

How about check wheter the user is already login or not in index.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    //in sidebar position, do checking
    if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] != '')
    {
        //if user already login succesfully, do anything here
    } else {
        //if user not yet login, display side bar
        include 'sidebar-signin-block.php
    }
    //your next index.php code
```

Comment: user4496955 Thank you for your answer. In the index.php code I did it like this: '<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){

 include ("sidebar-signin-block.php");
 }
 
 else {
  include ("sidebar-signin-block-logged-in.php"); 
 }

  ?>' It seems to be working fine and displays either included if logged or not logged. When I tried the code sample you provided it stopped working and I was unable to logout for some reason.

Comment: @Disaster Faster I don't understand why my code sample trouble logout proccess. thank you for your feedback

Comment: user4496955 You are very welcome! I greatly appreciate all of the hard work that users put in here to help others such as me. It is an extremely valuable resource that is worth it's weight in gold! I have learned a great deal of knowledge here and have solved many problems due to the contributions made by so many at this site. :-)